# PostGresql, creating a variable in a table that can get several values.

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables

I want to create a table with a variable called polygons that could take several values. Is it possible? And how I can insert Data to that table?
I am trying doing the following but I can’t. Any clues?

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (
    id integer,
    year integer,
    polygons integer[]
);
INSTER INTO test1 (id,year,polygons)
Values (1,2015,[12,52,53]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the correct way to define a column (not a variable) whose type is an array of values. However, an array literal is a string whose contents are enclosed in `{ }`:

```
INSERT INTO test1 (id, year, polygons)
VALUES (1, 2015, '{12, 52, 53}')
```

You can read more in the [documentation for arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html).